# Probability problem of cards

Tags: probability

Joe and I are playing card games. Each of us will draw 4 cards out of a deck of standard cards (52 cards). Suppose Joe first draw 4 cards, What is my  probability of getting at least 2 ace?

this is my thinking:
P (getting 2 ace)=P (joe not getting 3 ace or above  )*P (I get at least 2 ace)

P = ( 4*3*48*47+4*48*47*46+48*47*46*45)/(52*51*50*49) * (4*3*48*47+4*3*2*48+4*3*2*1)/(48*47*46*45)

am I correct?

Comment: Think you have to further split up the cases because some affect each other (e.g. When joe draws 2 aces "I" cannot draw 3 or 4 aces so the multiplication cannot follow directly).

Comment: A "faster" method: Even though Joe draws first, the fact that we didn't impose any condition on him means we can kind of treat Joe drawing like "shuffling the cards". So the probability required is the same as the probability of drawing at least 2 aces from a fresh deck.

Comment: Why we didnt impose condition on joe? Can you explain more please

Comment: Let's imagine ourselves dealing the cards. For the first case, we take 4 cards and pass it (face down) to Joe. We then give ourselves 4 cards. Compare it to the case where we shuffle or cut the deck by placing the top four cards at the back of the deck and then dealing 4 cards to ourself. (imposing a condition will be to say Joe has a King, for example. Then the two situations are different already because we have to look at his cards to get the King.)

Comment: Do you mean we can ignore what joe has draw and calculate the prob by cutting 4 cards? Sorry for my stupid question and poor english.

Comment: That's right. (note we must draw from a fresh deck. I.e. Over 52, etc.) Try to look at simpler examples (eg both Joe and I draw only one card and work out both ways to see why the hell works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: There are five cases: Joe gets $0-4$ aces on his draw. Then you can find the number of ways you can get $2+$ aces and divide that by the number of ways to choose $4$ cards, i.e. ${48 \choose 4}$

**Sub-hint**: In two of the cases, it will be impossible for you to get two or more aces, so get rid of them completely.